# Laravel OrderBy Random

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

As a novice in Laravel, i'm trying to display the images of a gallery randomly. In **routes.php**, I currently have this code:

```
// Get galleries
$galleries = App\Gallery::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Do you have any idea to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For Laravel >= 5.2 you could use **[`inRandomOrder()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)** method.

> **Description :** The `inRandomOrder()` method may be used to sort the query results randomly. For example, you may use this method to fetch a random user:

**Example :**

```
$galleries = App\Gallery::inRandomOrder()->get();
//Or
DB::table('gallery')->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

---

For other versions >= 5.0 you could use **[`random()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-random)** method.

> **Description :** The `random()` method returns a random item from the collection.

**Example :**

```
App\Gallery::all()->random()->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution gives an error : `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2161: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::inRandomOrder()`

Comment: It seems **inRandomOrder** is the problem. I still have the same error.

Comment: it is for >= laravel 5.2.. check your laravel version

Comment: Course::inRandomOrder()->take(20)->get();  Didn't work. - bad sort specification in Find.php line 219  
Also Course::all()->random()->get(); fetches the records but with same sequence, no difference. Am i missing something.
- Laravel version 5.6

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::random()

Answer (score 16):

You can try as:

```
$galleries = App\Gallery::orderByRaw('RAND()')->get()
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer, this solution makes no change, i still get a result as orderby ID

Comment: Are you running the exact query provided above or you are adding more to it?

Comment: I just add ; at the end

Comment: Don't add anything else to the query, just try the exact query provided above. I have tested it myself it's working.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to randomly sort a collection that has already been retrieved, you could use something like this

```
$result = $result->sortBy(function($item){
   return rand();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using laravel 8 (my case)
use

```
$galleries = App\Gallery::inRandomOrder()->get();
```